# Old fantasy movie about a boy on a quest for a blue rose at the top of a mountain

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this fantasy movie on TV around 1964 or 65. I believe it was black and white, live-action about a boy on a quest for a blue rose at the top of a mountain. Along the way he encounters a troll and a wind monster that blows him over. The monsters were incredible and I don’t know if they were puppets or what. I’ve never forgotten this movie but I’ve had no luck over the years identifying it. Aesthetics looked European, maybe it was dubbed, not sure. Anyone?

Comment: Might be the one from http://namethatmovie.org/35094/1960s-live-action-fantasy-of-a-boy-on-a-quest-for-a-blue-rose-and-the-monsters-he-encounters-it-was-not-the-thief-of-bagdad

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I'm guessing it's the same person who asked the question there, judging by the similarity of the descriptions and usernames.

Comment: That one also says it is not "The Thief of Bagdad".

Comment: @DoscoJones: That could be an issue. :)

Comment: The Blue rose reminds me of the 1961 color Thief of Baghdad which could have been seen on  black & white television.  The wind monster that blows someone over reminds me of Ilya Muromets/The Sword and the Dragon, a 1956 soviet epic fantasy film dubbed in English and released in the USA in 1960.  Possibly your memory mixed two movies into one.

Comment: Wait a minute... if the movie's in black-and-white, how do you know the rose is blue?

Answer (score 5):

This might be one of the versions of *[The Thief of Bagdad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief_of_Bagdad_(1940_film))*. From [this review of the 1961 film](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw4406596/?ref_=tt_urv):

> This ¨Thousand and one Nights¨ fare results to be an impressive fairy tale of a good and happy-go-lucky thief versus evil vizier full of fantastic elements . This one concerns a resourceful , handsome thief (Steve Reeves) helps a Sultan fight an evil Vizier , and win the hand of a beautiful Princess . This is an Oriental fantasy about ¨Thousand and one Arabian nights¨ plenty of incredible adventures, fantasy , witchery and wizardly. As a likeble thief falls in love for for a gorgeous princess (Giorgia Moll) whose father tries to marry off her , but she is poisened , as Steve and other suitors seek out the magical blue rose which is the antidote and all of them go across the seven fantastic doors . The wily young thief enlists the aid of a powerful genie (Chamarat) to face off the nasty and scheming Grand Vizier , Prince Osman (Arturo Dominici) who is helped by Gamal (Daniele Vargas). The malignant vizier with powerful magic faculties imprisons the princess . The thief then escapes thanks the magician and goes throughout the desert to find the antidote . The story accumulates several fantastic ingredients such as transformation of the starring, a flying horse, and of course , the sympathetic genie who gives wishes to Steve , among others.

### Trailer

### Blue Rose scene

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GayahQ6MzGU - Blue rose scene

Answer (score 2):

I'd been thinking the same thing as [M. A. Golding](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43538/m-a-golding).  "[Ilya Muromets](https://cinema.mosfilm.ru/films/34696/)" was the original Russian title.  "[The Sword and the Dragon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049358/?ref_=ttmi_tt)" was apparently the title used for [Roger Corman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Corman)'s 1960 English dubbed version.  There is also an [MST3K version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-9oH_moNRY).  Wind monster at 1:30.

I'm wondering if you've mixed memories of this and "[Thief of Baghdad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief_of_Bagdad_(1940_film))"?